# Does the boundary of metric balls have measure $0$ in a metric measure space with Radon measure?

Tags: measure-theory, metric-spaces

Let $(X,d,m)$ be a metric measure space such that $m$ is a Radon measure and let $\overline{B}(x,r):=\{y\in X \mid d(x,y)\leq r\}$. Is it true that the "boundary" of $\overline{B}$ (meaning the set $\{y\in X \mid d(x,y)=r\}$) has $m$ measure $0$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. For a trivial example consider a finite metric space.

For a less trivial example, consider $\Bbb R$ with Lebesgue measure, but
with the metric $d(x,y)=\min(|x-y|,1)$, which generates the usual topology.

Comment: You have $d(x,x)=1$ which is a problem.

Comment: Does it definitely generate the usual topology? Are single points not open sets in this metric space? Eg, $B(0,0.5)=\{x: d(x,0)<0.5\}=\{0\}$?

Comment: @eranreches I assume you can impose $d(x,x)=0$ separate from the above definition. I mean metrics aren't required to be continuous maps in principle. I don't know much about radon measures though.

Comment: @eranreches I think the triangle inequality looks okay just from a sketch

Comment: I think it's a $\min$ and not a $\max$, so it's just a typo

Comment: @Max Thanks, Max, or is your name really Min?

Comment: @LordSharktheUnknown : like you, it shall forever be unknown